# Extruding from a logarithmic curve

Tags: add-on

I have ran into an issue with Blender that I can't seem to wrap my head around. Using the curve addon available in Blender, I have created this:

[image: Spiral]

Now that's all fine and well and I have it the way I want it to, but trying to extrude it on the Z axis, only does this:

[image: Failed extrude]

As you can see, it is only extruding from two points, while I been trying to get it to extrude from all to form a wall of sorts, using two circles, I have managed to make a 'somewhat' accurate spiral, but it's far from the perfection of the logarithmic spiral:

[image: Main goal]

So my question is simple, how do I get from extruding in only two points, to extruding on all the vertices, so that I can get some height on the Z axis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a curve and therefore it does not have any edges to extrude. Only control points. You could either change the extrude and/or depth values in the curve's *Object Data Properties*:

[image]

Or convert the Curve to a Mesh and extrude in *Edit Mode*:

[image]

Comment: That works wonders, thank you very much for your help.